# Transition Matrix for a non-trivial example

Tags: transition-matrix

So I've just been introduced to Transition Matrices; and I was wondering what one for look like the following example:

"Symmetric random walk on the integers"

$S$ $=$ $\mathbb{Z}$, $\forall$ $i$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$, $\forall$ $n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$

Obviously for this we know that $p_{i,i+1}$ $=$ $p_{i,i-1}$ $=$ 0.5

And I've been told to write out the transition matrix for this, but I'm very not sure what it is.

Comment: It's a bi-infinite matrix.  All you have to do is write the transition probabilities. As far as most people are concerned you have *already* written them, so could you tell us what it means to "write out" the matrix?

Comment: Just a bit uncertain of how it would be structured as a transition matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either move up or down but not stay:

$P = \left[\begin{matrix}
\ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots& \ddots & \ddots & \ddots\\
\ddots & 0.5 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\
\ldots & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & \ldots \\
\ldots & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0.5 & \ddots \\
\ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots& \ddots & \ddots & \ddots\\
\end{matrix}\right]$

Comment: So it'd look like. ...,0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, ..., and then next row it'd be like ..., 0.5, 0,0.5,0,... in the same columns, am I correct?

Comment: Updated, looks strange now but the "middle" zeros are on the main diagonal.

Comment: And I'm assuming the 0's on the left of the second top row, and the 0 on the right of the second bottom row also extend to the left and the right respectively?